# Execute lb MIPS instruction by hand

Tags: mips

I am working on executing MIPS instructions by hand and I am not really understanding how it works. In the example given below, the contents in $t0 changes from 0x00001117 to 0x00000080. I do not understand why though. Any help would be great.

```
lbu $t0, 5($s0)
lbu (i-type, load byte unsigned) 
Registers before                Instruction Registers after
Register       Contents            Register       Contents
$t0         0x00001117          $t0         0x00000080
$s0         0x10010010          $s0         0x10010010
$pc         0x0040008c          $pc         0x00400090


Memory before                   Memory After
Location    Contents            Location    Contents
0x10010010  0x00400004          0x10010010  0x00400004
0x10010014  0x00408008          0x10010014  0x00408008
0x10010018  0x0040001c          0x10010018  0x0040001c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes a little-endian memory layout.

`$s0` has the value `0x10010010`, so `5($s0)` refers to the value at address `0x10010015`.

Your memory contents when viewed as bytes looks like this:

```
            +0 +1 +2 +3
-----------------------
0x10010010: 04 00 40 00
0x10010014: 08 80 40 00
...
```

As you can see, the byte at `0x10010015` is `0x80`. And since `lbu` zero-extends the loaded value to 32 bits, the upper 24 bits of `$t0` are cleared.

Comment: That makes so much more sense. Thank you!